# Nested expressions in custom conditions of classic pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to simplify a complex pipeline, and part of that is to use custom conditions to execute only parts of the pipeline (mostly for testing purposes, but also for some functional reasons).

I want to nest expressions, but can't seem to get it to work because it seems like the variables are not being evaluated.  Example:

Variables:

PerformSonar: `false` (settable at queue time)

expPerformSonar: `and(succeeded(), eq(PerformSonar, true))`

Then in my sonar step, I set the custom condition to

`eq(variables['expPerformSonar'], true)` // always evaluates to false, variables expanded as text

I've tried numerous syntax variations, tried using compile time and runtime expression syntax, all sorts of things and it all fails

Example:

`eq('${{ variables['expPerformSonar'] }}', true)` - evaluates false, variables not expanded as text

The only thing that seems to work is putting the full expression in the Custom Condition field.

Is there any way to decompose conditions and use them in nested situations in classic pipelines?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT - i haven't had the time to try it yet, sorry

Comment: Not getting your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to decompose conditions and use them in nested
> situations in classic pipelines?

The definition `expPerformSonar: and(succeeded(), eq(PerformSonar, true))` is not the right way to define variables with expressions.

Check [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) document:

```
# Two examples of expressions used to define variables
# The first one, a, is evaluated when the YAML file is parsed into a plan.
# The second one, b, is evaluated at run time. 
# Note the syntax ${{}} for parse time and $[] for runtime expressions.
variables:
  a: ${{ <expression> }}
  b: $[ <expression> ]
```

No matter Classic pipeline or Yaml pipeline, if you want to define variable using expressions. You should choose format `${{ <expression> }}` or `$[ <expression> ]` instead of a direct expression.

**Here's my working example for your scenario:**

1.Your variables could be:

**PerformSonar**: `false`

**expPerformSonar**: `$[ eq(variables['PerformSonar'], 'true') ]`

2.And the conditon could be:

```
and(succeeded(),eq(variables['expPerformSonar'], true))
```

PS: It's recommended to use `succeeded()` **directly** in task/step's condition instead of using it when defining variables.

Comment: I thought i'd tried that variation.. but i'll give it a try again, sorry that was a typo above with the variable usage, I meant variables.expPerformSonar (which is basically the same as variables['expPerformSonar'])

Comment: @ErikRS To define the second variable via expressions, you need to use format `${{ <expression> }}` or `$[ <expression> ]`. The `and(succeeded(), eq(PerformSonar, true))` is a expression, we shouldn't define variable directly using expression.

Comment: @ErikRS You can check my working example on your side. Hope it also works for your scenario :)